# Cleaning up 404 Errors with 301 mod rewrite or a pretty solution

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have multiple web sites for my clients and each client has a directory labelled articles. I just inherited this system and I until I can fix the issue I found, I am looking for stopgap solution, one that will eliminate the 404 errors after a file has been deleted.

All these directories have static pages for the articles, as well as an index page that lists all the articles.

Based on the logs it generates many errors from over the years. I can just imagine it is causing havoc the search engines as well.
With little knowledge of mod rewrite that I have, I managed to put this together which I plan to put into place within the Apache configuration. Before I do, is this good solution or is there something else I should do.

```
<Directory "/home/www/public_html/clients">
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/articles/index.html [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is looking to see if the file exists and if does display it while ignoring the rest of rewrite.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is looking to see if the directory exists and if does display it while ignoring the rest of rewrite.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]` grabs the domain to passes it to the last rewrite as 301 redirect.

I have it working locally and like a few opinions before making live.

Comment: Maybe not a great idea as for this line in the rewrite effects all files all the time when a page is accessed. Does this slow down Apache running mod rewrite on hundreds of sites? If doesn't I could create a common redirect for all errors like this > RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/404.html [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No need for `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]` line -- just replace your `%1` in RewriteRule by `%{HTTP_HOST}`
2. From rewriting point of view the solution is OK
3. From **SEO** point of view -- not so sure -- better have it 404 or 410 instead (since the article is no longer there). I think it will be better to display custom page to the customer while sending 404 or 410 to the browser:

   - Browser/Search Engine will see error code
   - User will see explanation instead while offered to see related to the requested URL pages/short index.
4. From **User** point of view -- not good: I would like to know that URL/article is no longer available straight away (see #3) and browse your site around if I find it useful, rather than seeing some irrelevant (at first) index page and telling myself -- I do not remember clicking this link, and go back to search engine/referral and click again. If I will see the same index page again -- I understand (most likely) that something wrong with that page and just turn away (unless I **really** interested in that page's content).

---

**UPDATE:**

I would do it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/articles/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /articles/notfound.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

1. Redirect non-existing URLs to notfound.php (or whatever else name it may have) ONLY if requested URL has anything to do with articles (URL starts with `/articles/`)
2. On that page (has to be dynamic (PHP or similar) and not static HTML) respond with `410 Gone` Error Code (for browser/spider) and display a page explaining that this URL is no longer here but you can look at these links (and some useful links -- could be mini-index/recent articles etc) -- this is for user.

Comment: I am OK with generating a custom 404 error. Do I do this with rewrite I suggested above? Or is there another method I can do this. Again, I am very wet behind the ears on this sort of thing.

Comment: @Tim I have updated my answer with the way how I would go. You can catch all other non-articles non-existing documents with generic 404 page or create your own (e.g. using this directive `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` or by creating another rewrite rule that will point to such 404 page).

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going your suggestion(s) tomorrow. Will defiantly get back. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay to get back to you. I decided to try the ErrorDocument 404, this was great. Except a global version does not work for IE, does for all other browsers. Strange! So I am back to your other idea on the mod rewrite and see about making it global.

Have you ever heard of IE not responding to a global error page? This is what I done and works for all other browsers > Alias /errors/ "/home/errors/" ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php

Comment: @Tim 1) How big that page is? IE (at least old versions) would display their own page if server generated page is less than 512 bytes. 2) If you could show me your real URL I would look into it as well (maybe my IE will tell something different).

Comment: Just read that on Apache, I was just testing this out so yes it was below the 512 bytes. When I changed it to include each web sites template I am over that threshold, which now gives me custom 404 pages for all these web sites without actually making one for each. Love it! I appreicate your help, these tips you shown me lead me to the right searches and to figure this mess out. I am one happy camper! Many thanks.

Comment: In the end here is what I have and I am happy with. Done all tests and ready to go live. Trying to post my code, and having a problem. Not use to doing it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be valid, at least it should work :-)

About the 301 redirect you make a permanent redirect from an article page to a page that, if I understand well, list available articles. A better HTTP code exist for vanished ressources it's `410 Gone`:

> The requested resource is no longer
>   available at the server and no
>   forwarding address is known. This
>   condition is expected to be considered
>   permanent. Clients with link editing
>   capabilities SHOULD delete references
>   to the Request-URI after user
>   approval. If the server does not know,
>   or has no facility to determine,
>   whether or not the condition is
>   permanent, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) SHOULD be used instead. This
>   response is cacheable unless indicated
>   otherwise.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended
>   to assist the task of web maintenance
>   by notifying the recipient that the
>   resource is intentionally unavailable
>   and that the server owners desire that
>   remote links to that resource be
>   removed. Such an event is common for
>   limited-time, promotional services and
>   for resources belonging to individuals
>   no longer working at the server's
>   site. It is not necessary to mark all
>   permanently unavailable resources as
>   "gone" or to keep the mark for any
>   length of time -- that is left to the
>   discretion of the server owner.

So it would be a 'better 404', that maybe crawlers will prefer, at least it's the HTTP way. If you really want a Redirect behaviour (maybe better for humans) then the 301 is the right choice, but crawlers may detect a lot of previous ressources links to the same new content. On the other hand it's something often done, so I'm quite sure you won't have any problems.

301 vs 410 is hard to decide actually. There's alos the Redirect `303 See Other` which is a ...redirect, but sadly the main goal of 303 is more a **redirect after post** than a 410-with-redirect. With a 303 the old url is not removed from search indexes.

Last problem, all random url (legitime 404) will get a response (301+200 or 410), which can lead to false positive for somme fuzzy attackers in the redirect case... but false positive is maybe a good thing for theses scripts, they'll loose time on that.